# Fastest way to filter a string

Tags: unix, text

I'm working on a script that reads the header of some files (medical images), filters the data and then creates a file directory based on that data.
But there are millions of images and I need to make it faster in a task.
After reading the image, the script creates a block of information that I need to filter, swap the letters accented by normal letters, swap any space for an underline, and then delete any character other than "**AZ, AZ, 0-9,_)( ][-"**.
At the moment I use the SED and Tr commands as shown below, Is there a faster way to do this ? TIA

```
BLOCK=$( command to read the images ) 
FILTER=$( echo $BLOCK | tr 'ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúçÇ ^\' 'AEIOUaeioucC_:' | sed -e 's/[^A-_a-z0-9() -]//g' )
```

Comment: Did you check the execution time of `command to read the images`? I'm nearly sure that this takes much longer than the `echo .. | tr ... | sed ...` pipeline, so optimizing that won't help (even though you could go with only `tr` here for a tiny bit of performance)

Comment: yes, it consumes about 15% of the script time. But I can not change it, so I need to improve performance at another point.
In  script I do not use 'echo'  but  FILTER = $ (command | tr '' '' | sed -e '').
I separated in two parts here  just to be more understandable.

Comment: What consumes the other 85%?

Comment: filter, separate the data in name, date, id, type, create new directories with this data, copy the files to these directories and put the operation in a log

Comment: So I put my bet on the copy operation :-) If you run this on a multi-core system (aka any recent hardware) look for ways to parallelize the whole processing and maybe kick the copy process into the background (or collect all the copy commands in a file and run them afterwards/over night).

Comment: For curiosity, I have taken the times of each process. I have :
Find / loop = 8% of time, Command read images 15%, create directories 11%, copy files 6%, logs 1%, filter data 15%, transform the block of data into variable name, date, id etc = 30% 
I will use it in approximately 40 million images, the calculation to finish the task is about 1000 hours! So every thousandth of a second less helps me a lot.

Comment: As I said: parallelize :-)

Comment: Or use a Perl/Python script to drive the process, not a bunch of utilities combined with a shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not address the "faster way" part of the question: more of a code review

1. make sure to quote your variables: `echo "$BLOCK"`
2. "delete any character other than "AZ, AZ, 0-9,_)( ][-" ->

   ```
   tr -dc '][:alnum:]_)( [-'
   ```

   where `-d` means "delete" and `-c` mean "the complement of the given set". `[:alnum:]` is a character class matching letters and numbers.

Comment: Thanks, it got faster, but I had to change it a bit.
 tr -dc '][:alnum:]_)(\n [-' )